# MakeFile in g++ . Ignorable commands

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I am learning how to make `Makefile` in g++. I am using the following [example](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/)
The codes for the project is [here](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/writing-makefiles/download/).This is the Makefile

```
# Makefile for Writing Make Files Example

# *****************************************************
# Variables to control Makefile operation

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g

# ****************************************************
# Targets needed to bring the executable up to date

main: main.o Point.o Rectangle.o  # ***Statement : 1 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o main main.o Point.o Rectangle.o  #Commands underneath dependencies have tabs before them

# The main.o target can be written more simply

main.o: Point.h Rectangle.h           # ***Statement : 2
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c main.cpp

Point.o: Point.h                      # ***Statement : 3 


Rectangle.o: Rectangle.h Point.h      # ***Statement : 4
```

Now I have some questions regarding this I have also referenced specific lines using the statement keyword for ease of questioning.

1- Is my understanding correct of statement 1. When g++ encounters main.o (which is a dependency for target main.o) after main: it jumps to target main.0 (statement 2) . It then checks the dependency of main.o if the dependency (the two header files are found) it then runs the command.then it comes back up to complete its task for the next dependency and so on ??

2-For dependency of Point.o which is Point.h why is there no command as such

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c Point.cpp
```

and similarly for Rectangle.o why is there no command for its dependency as such

$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c Rectangle.cpp

I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this.

Comment: You are missing `xxx.cpp` as dependency for `xxx.o`...

Comment: @PiotrNycz My version of gnu make (3.81) implicitly adds that dependency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Correct. It is worth noting that gnu `make` uses modification time to determine whether a dependencies are met.
2. `make` has [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) for building `.o` targets. These use variables such as `$CXX` and `$CXXFLAGS`. For a given target, say `foo.o`, `make` will apply a rule depending on the presence of a source file `foo.<ext>`, creating a target-dependency pair `foo.o : foo.<ext>`. If the extension is a C++ one (e.g. `.cpp`, `.cc`, `.C`), then it will apply a rule along the lines of

   `$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c`

You have specified *extra dependency* for `Point.o`. This is added to the implicit dependency `Point.cpp`. If the modification time of either `Point.h` or `Point.cpp` is newer than that of `Point.o`, the rule will be run.

As @Basile has pointed out in comments, you can invoke `make` with the `-p` or `--print-data-base` options to get information on the "state" of make, including the implicit rules. Using it with grep, for example, I can query the implicit rules for building `.o` files from C++ files:

```
make -p | grep -A 1 -B 1 COMPILE.cc
```

Output:

```
# default
COMPILE.cpp = $(COMPILE.cc)
# makefile (from `Makefile', line 1)
--
--
# default
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
# environment
--
--
# default
COMPILE.C = $(COMPILE.cc)
# environment
--
--
#  commands to execute (built-in):
        $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

--
--
#  commands to execute (built-in):
        $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

Concerning the rule you extended, `Point.o : Point.h`, this is what my version of make would produce:

```
make -p | grep -A 1 -B 1 Point
....
Point.o: Point.cpp Point.h
#  Implicit rule search has been done.
....
```

Comment: run `make -p` to understand the implicit rules.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Good suggestion. I added an example.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. One final question you stated that "the implicit rule will be run when those dependencies are not met. By default, an implicit rule for object Point.o would only depend on a source file such as Point.cpp.". The extra dependency of Point.o is Point.h which in this case is met. Will the implicit rule still run in this case ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar It will run if either `Point.h` or `Point.cpp` has a newer modification time than `Point.o`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is it correct to assume that your initial statement "the implicit rule will be run when those dependencies are not met .." was misleading ? since the dependency of `Point.o` is `Point.h` and it was met. ? Or did i misunderstand the statement ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar I added some explanations. I hope it is clearer now.